# changing last listitem of listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hi friends i am new on android . i have a Custom listview that each item contain single text and Image view first of all i use the single image for all the listitem then i use an array list on that on click i add one element after that i notify the dataset changed but the thing is that it's just only updating the last item of the listview here is my code below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] countries = { "pakistan", "china", "russia", "indonesia", "japan",
        "bangladesh", "Brazil", "india", "nigeria",
        "united states of america" };
String[] population = { "180 million", "1500 million", "160 million",
        "200 million", "140 million", "160 million", "200 million",
        "1200 million", "120 million", "280 million" };
int[] images = { R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.russia,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.nigeria,
        R.drawable.unitedstates };

ArrayList<String> compare=new ArrayList<String>();

int mode = 1;
Context context;
Animation anim,anim1;
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = MainActivity.this;

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv.setAdapter(new adopter(this));

    Button stopAnim=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopanimation);
    stopAnim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(i<countries.length){
                compare.add(countries[i]);
                i++;
            }


            BaseAdapter nain=new adopter(MainActivity.this);
            nain.notifyDataSetChanged();

            lv.setAdapter(nain);


        }
    });


    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Animationbutt);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

}

class adopter extends BaseAdapter {
    final LayoutInflater layoutinflator;

    public adopter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        layoutinflator = getLayoutInflater();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return countries.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listitem = convertView;
        int pos = position;
        // listitem = layoutinflator.inflate(R.layout.anotherxml, null);
        listitem = layoutinflator.inflate(R.layout.another1, null);

        // TextView tv = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        // TextView tv1 = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
         TextView tv = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.Songtitle);

         tv.setText(countries[pos]);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Log.d("Compare size is this","#"+compare.size());

        if(compare.size()!=0){

                for(int j=0;j<compare.size();j++){
                    if(countries[pos].equalsIgnoreCase(compare.get(j).toString())){
                        Log.d("Countries compare are this", "hasnain"+countries[pos]);
                         iv.setBackgroundResource(images[pos]);
                    }else{

                        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pakistan);
                    }


            }

        }else{
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pakistan);
        }

        return listitem;
    }

}

}
```

i am unable to understand this behaviour kindly help

Comment: **What's your issue exactly?** do you want to change last item view or want to understand why it's happening?

Comment: what u want exactly???

Comment: actually i make an array list that add the item on button click after that i call the adapter with notify dat changed first if i click once on button i want to change the image of first comparing list item the after second click my array list size now becames 2 now it want to change the 2 list item image but its only change the last comparing listitem image that is the issue

Comment: you need not set adapter twice calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will do

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the `notifyDataSetChanged()` construct. The idea is to keep the same adapter and modify the list that you have fed it.

So, store the adapter as an instance variable, then modify the list it uses (countries) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. For this to work you should use `ArrayList<String>` (or another List implementation) instead of `String[]`, because the length of `String[]` cannot be modified.

Comment: actually sir i am not ppending or any thing in string array i just only add an element in Arraylist with name compre on button click then i am trying to compre the array list string with listitem text string if its compare then it will change the imageview of comparing item but it only change the imageview of last comparing item ok i also change the adapter in my above code but it still shows the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You are creating adapter each time of the button click. Don't do that.Create an instance of adapter and initialize it in onCreate. In button click just notify the adapter.

Code is here...

```
adopter my_adapter ; 
 @Override protected void onCreate(BundlesavedInstanceState) {
 ...
 ... 
my_adapter = newadopter(MainActivity.this); 
lv.setAdapter(my_adapter);
 ...
 ...
 Button stopAnim=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopanimation);
     stopAnim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             if(i<countries.length){
                compare.add(countries[i]);
                 i++;
             }
            my_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
     });

 }
```